# Initialize lighbox for img tag

Tags: jquery, html, image, lightbox

I have an image in my content. When I click on the image I need to open it in an jquery popup.

My image structure is :

```
<img height="213" width="480" src="http://www.test.com/sites/default/files/styles/large/public/avatar-configure.png" typeof="foaf:Image" class="media-image" alt="">
```

I couldn't alter the image structure. Is there any jquery plugin support this type of functionality? Please help me.

Comment: Are you using a specific lightbox library?

Comment: `I need to open it in an jquery popup.` what do you mean by this. Is it `window.open()` kind of question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest this lightbox:

http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/

Comment: Sorry I can comment only here and don't get what you're up to. That's how things work.

Comment: You can eventually use jquery ui attaching dialog to id
http://jqueryui.com/dialog/ But I wouldn't recommend adding jqUI only for this. I'm sure there are other plugins out there just google it.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend the wonderful Fancybox plugin

http://fancybox.net/

http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/  (v2)

for fancybox 2

```
<a class="fancybox" rel="group" href="big_image_1.jpg"><img src="small_image_1.jpg" alt="" /></a>
<a class="fancybox" rel="group" href="big_image_2.jpg"><img src="small_image_2.jpg" alt="" /></a>


<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".fancybox").fancybox();
    });
</script>
```